# Use VBScript in HTML to write a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm trying to use VBScript in HTML to write text into what will become a powershell script.  I am doing this to avoid having to statically code into my HTA the location of these powershell scripts.

My problem becomes working around Powershell's `"` `(` and `)`

An example, I'm just not sure how to wrap the characters in order to keep VBS happy.

```
Dim filesys, filetxt
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("c:\Temp\somefile.txt", ForAppending, True)
filetxt.WriteLine ("Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]")
filetxt.WriteLine ("[string]$Str)")
filetxt.WriteLine ("# Create the IE com object")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$ie = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application")
filetxt.WriteLine ("#Navigate to www.")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$ie.navigate("http://www.page.com")")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that last line is your only issue, you can escape the quotes either by doubling them up or by using Chr(34) to programatically insert them.

```
filetxt.WriteLine ("$ie.navigate(""http://www.page.com"")")

filetxt.WriteLine ("$ie.navigate(" & Chr(34) & "http://www.page.com" & Chr(34) & ")")
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple!  Ended up using `filetxt.WriteLine ("$ie.navigate(" & Chr(34) & "http://www.website.com" & Chr(34) & ")")`  But now I'm stuck on trying to delete the temporary script created.  VBS is telling me Permission denied for `filesys.DeleteFile "c:\Temp\somefile.txt"`

Comment: Did you try the optional force argument on the DeleteFile command: `filesys.DeleteFile "c:\temp\somefile.txt", True`?  Make sure you're closing the filestream first with `filetxt.Close` if you're performing this within the same script.

Otherwise, it may be a permissions issue, in which case you could try to elevate the permissions within VBScript using the ShellExecute/runas method here:  http://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html

Comment: Ended up using `filedelete.DeleteFile "c:\temp\temp.ps1"` which works.  Thanks again!

Comment: Just for follow up, I'm using `filesys.DeleteFile (filesys.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\FileName.ps1")` where `Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`